# How can I call an MVC FileContentResult by Jquery and get it to prompt the user to save on it's return?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, filecontentresult

I'm generating a CSV from an MVC 3 website and using a FileContentResult to pass this to the user.  This worked great but it took 30 seconds for the csv to generate and therefore 30 seconds before the prompt to save was given to the user.

```
    public virtual FileContentResult GetSpreadsheet(string id)
    {
        var service = new SpreadsheetService();
        var result = service.GetCSV();
        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(result.Message), "text/csv", "Report123.csv");
    }
```

So I thought I'd just call it via JQuery - but this (unsurprisingly!) just dumps the CSV to the page.

```
            $.post("/Home/GetSpreadsheet/" + id, null, function (data) {
                $('#resultDiv').html(data);
            });
```

Does anyone know how I'd generate the prompt to save now I've got the data back?  Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do that. Forget about that. It is impossible to download files using AJAX. In fact the AJAX call will work, you will hit the server, the server will send the file contents back to the client, the AJAX success callback will be triggered and passed as argument the contents of the file and that's where everything ends for you. Using javascript you cannot, for absolutely obvious reasons, save directly the file to the client computer and you cannot prompt for the Save As dialog.

So instead of using AJAX simply create an anchor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("download spreadsheet", "GetSpreadsheet", new { id = "123" })
```

Now if the server set the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment` the browser will prompt the user to download and save the file at some chosen location on his computer.

Comment: You can also set the content-type header to the appropriate type if known, to prompt an open or save dialog (in most cases) For example: Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel or text/csv

Comment: Love the answer.  Made me think about that song "Screamager" by Therapy.

Comment: What are those "absolutely obvious" reasons? I managed to get the file bytes using ajax, I just need to render them

Comment: I'm seconding what @Nick says here: one can, in fact, not only get the data, but cause the browser to download it without any further user interaction. The only problem is that the data gets mangled in the process...

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to use an anchor, use a hidden iframe and set the src of the iframe to the url of the file to be downloaded.

```
<iframe id="hiddenFrame" src="" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;"></iframe>
```

Instead of the '$.post(...)' line use:

```
 downloadSpreadsheet('123');

 function downloadSpreadsheet(id) {
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/YourControllerName/GetSpreadsheet")' + "?id=" + id;
    $('#hiddenFrame').attr('src', url);
}
```

Or you can give a try on the [jQuery Plugin for Requesting Ajax-like File Downloads](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/.)

Using the plugin, you can download by invocking:

```
jQuery.download(url, data, method)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this in JavaScript:

```
function downloadSpreadsheet(id) {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("GetSpreadsheet", "Home")?id=' + id;
}
```