# Downloadable data link for HTTP POST using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, http-post, content-disposition

I have an HTTP POST REST endpoint that consumes an image and returns an HTML document with pixel data from the image. The HTTP response includes the header **Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Pixels.html** so that the browser would prompt for downloading.

I would like to have an HTML/JavaScript (not jQuery) app that

1. allows me to browse and pick an image (e.g., `<input id="fid" name="fid" type="file" />`
2. on clicking a link post the image data to the endpoint and let me download the HTML content to the disk (e.g., `<p onclick="javascript: getPixels()">Get Pixels</p>`).

How do I go about doing this? I tried the following code:

```
  function getPixels() {
     var input = document.getElementById("fid");
     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onload = function (e) {
              var imgData = e.target.result;
              var postUrl = "./GetPixelsService.svc/image";
              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.open("POST", postUrl);
              xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
              //xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
              //   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
              //      var res_display = document.getElementById("results");
              //      res_display.srcdoc = xhr.responseText;
              //   }
              //}
              xhr.send(imgData);
           };
           reader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
        }
     }
  }
```

The following is the HTML blurb that calls the above function.

```
  <p>
     Upload the image here:
  </p>
  <input id="fid" name="fid" type="file" />
  <!--<button type="submit" onclick="javascript: getPixels()">Get Pixels</button>-->
  <p onclick="javascript: getPixels()">Get Pixels</p>
  <p />
  <hr />
  <p>
     <img id="img2check" src="" alt="" />
  </p>
  <p />
  <iframe id="results" style="width: 100%; border: 0; height: 400px;" src="javascript:;">
     Your browser does not support iframes.
  </iframe>
```

I am able to pick the response and display it in an iframe, but unable to get the browser to download the content.

Appreciate your help. I have looked at the relevant questions on StackOverflow, but none has helped so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to er-han, the following code achieves the goal.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function getPixels() {
           showImage();
           var input = document.getElementById("fid");
           if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
              if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                 var reader = new FileReader();
                 reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var imgData = e.target.result;
                    var postUrl = "./SimpleService.svc/image";
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("POST", postUrl);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                       if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                          var res_url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([xhr.responseText]));
                          var lnk = document.getElementById("dlink");
                          lnk.href = res_url;
                          lnk.style.display = "block";
                       }
                    }
                    xhr.send(imgData);
                 };
                 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
              }
           }
        }

        function showImage() {
           var input = document.getElementById("fid");
           if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
              if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                 var reader = new FileReader();
                 reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var img_display = document.getElementById("img2check");
                    img_display.src = e.target.result;
                 };
                 reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
              }
           }
        }
     </script>

     <p>
        Upload the image here:
     </p>
     <input id="fid" name="fid" type="file" />
     <p/>
     <button type="submit" onclick="javascript: getPixels()">Upload</button>
     <p />
     <hr />
     <p>
        <img id="img2check" src="" alt="" />
     </p>
     <p />
     <p>
        <a id="dlink" href="#" download="Data.html" style="display: none;">Download data</a>
     </p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I hadn't time to work on it sorry, but i am glad you did it. I am sure i am going to need this proper answer in the future :)

Comment: Appreciate your help. Wouldn't have been able to do it without it. Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't force the client browser to prompt a save dialog with an XMLHttpRequest.

What you can do are followings:

**1:** Check this answer of mine to another question similar to this: [How to get pdf file via javascript ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720066/how-to-get-pdf-file-via-javascript-ajax/41720808#41720808)

**2:** Generate the file on server or create a `get` type request handler and give link to it with `download` attribute.
http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_a_download.asp

**3:** Use 3rd party apps like Downloadify: https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

**4:** There is another way using `Blob`, which i haven't tried yet, in here: [Browser/HTML Force download of image from src="data:image/jpeg;base64..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473932/browser-html-force-download-of-image-from-src-dataimage-jpegbase64). This post is about a base64 image, but i think it's worth to try with an `html` file.

Comment: Thank you. I tried creating a URL via Blob, but that did not work: the contents of the URL got dumped to the page instead. I will take another look.

Comment: The server-side is REST, so what it is expecting is just the image binary. That's why I didn't go through the forms approach (which would encode the image binary). Is there a way to send just the image binary via form?

Comment: Thank you. A combination of (2) and (4) does the magic. I will post the whole solution as an answer for the benefit of others. Thanks again ...